# How to @link to overridden Enum method in JavaDoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

Suppose I have an enum structure as follows:

```
public enum TransportMode {
    BYCICLE {
        @Override
        public double speedFactor() { return .7; }
    },
    CAR {
        @Override
        public double speedFactor() { return 1; }
    },
    TRAIN {
        /**
         * Faster than train (see also {@link TransportMode#CAR#speedFactor()}). 
         */
        @Override
        public double speedFactor() { return 1.3; }
    };

    public abstract double speedFactor();
}
```

When generating Javadoc with maven-source-plugin 3.0.1, I get the following warning:

> [WARNING] D:\path\TransportMode.java:000: warning - Tag @see: can't
>   find CAR#speedFactor() in TransportMode

I get the same result when leaving out the class altogether.

Is this a bug? IntelliJ seems to resolve the path fine.

Comment: @zlakad this is just a simplified example.